Wordpress site calling debug.log and .user.ini at certain hour
Im having a hard time understanding what is this behaviour. I have around 300 Wordpress Sites on two big servers. They normally work pretty well, but from some time to now, they started to have a weird behaviour when one of the servers at 4 pm every two days and the other at 1pm also every two days starts to call like crazy their own debug.log file and .user.ini file.
Heres the error message that nginx log gives because i have disabled .log access by rule.
2024/07/17 16:00:44 [error] 88558#88558: *543 access forbidden by rule, client: 140.8.xx.xx (its my own server ip), server: xxxx.com, request: "GET /wp-content/debug.log 

I don´t have an idea of what could be causing this calls. After i restart the server several times over 10 minutes, everything goes back to normal.
